# Indices in PROC DATASETS, PROC SQL for SAS and ORACLE libraries

Tags: oracle, indexing, sas, proc-sql

I'm a bit confused about the use of indexes in SAS.

I found 2 ways of implementing them :

[with PROC SQL](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002473673.htm)

```
CREATE <UNIQUE> INDEX index-name 
 ON table-name ( column <, ... column>);
```

[with PROC DATASETS](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000440261.htm)

```
proc datasets library=college;
   modify survey;
      index create class;
      index create major;
run;

proc datasets library=college;
   modify maillist;
      index create zipid=(zipcode schoolid);
run;

proc datasets library=college;
   modify student;
      index create idnum / unique;
run;

proc datasets library=college;
   modify student;
      index create religion / nomiss;
run;
```

---

My first question is, do they do the same thing ? I would assume they do but given the doc doesn't seem to cross reference them and that there is no option for `nomiss` in `PROC SQL`, I have some doubts.

---

My second question is, given I have Oracle libraries and SAS libraries, what is the relations between indices defined in ORACLE to those defined in SAS ?

The following query runs very fast, because the table was indexed in the Oracle DB:

```
PROC SQL;
  SELECT * FROM ORACLELIB.MY_TABLE
  WHERE RELATION_ID = 1097;
QUIT;
```

But if I try to do a simple inner join on a 1 column, 1 observation, indexed table located in my `WORK` library, the query takes an awful lot of time:

```
data TEST;
   input RELATION_ID;
   datalines;
   1097
;

proc datasets library=WORK;
   modify TEST;
      index create RELATION_ID;
run;

PROC SQL;
  SELECT * FROM ORACLELIB.MY_TABLE t1
  INNER JOIN TEST t2
  ON t1.RELATION_ID = t2.RELATION_ID;
QUIT;
```

This is also slow :

```
PROC SQL;
  SELECT * FROM ORACLELIB.MY_TABLE t1
  WHERE RELATION_ID IN (SELECT RELATION_ID FROM TEST);
QUIT;
```

I also tried to create my test table in an oracle library, which is not located on the same oracle server) :

```
data ORACLELIB2.TEST;
   input RELATION_ID;
   datalines;
   1097
;
```

This seems to be just as slow (In this case I cannot index it due to restrictions but it's only one observation).

---

Which leads to my last question, what can I do to make this join run as fast as it should ?

---

*Additional notes:*

I have 3 servers:

- the main ORACLE server, where I cannot write, which contains the library featuring MY_TABLE
- Another ORACLE server, where I can write.
- A SAS server, where I can write

My main use will be queries of the following type:

```
CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE AS
SELECT *columns* FROM smaller_table t1 LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE t2
ON t1.RELATION_ID = t2.RELATION_ID and t1.other_col = t2.other col
WHERE *additional restrictions on t2*;
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to investigate the `SASTRACE=` option ([9.2 docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000433982.htm)) that will log what the remote library engine is doing.  I would have expected the engine to do it's own implicit pass-through on simple joins.  The engine will translate some SAS functions and grouping clauses automatically to Oracle side equivalents.

If you are unable to get server side to operate in expected fast ways, for small sets of IDs {a couple thousand}) consider code generating an `IN` list and see if that performs better.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select relation_id into :id_list separated by ',' from test;

  SELECT * FROM ORACLELIB.MY_TABLE t1
  WHERE RELATION_ID IN (&id_list);
quit;
```

If the ids are character, the code generator will have to `quote()` the values in the select.

Comment: That's a good point Richard, I thought about this strategy using `IN` to prefilter my table before joining, but a couple of thousands is few, I'll be generally playing with values in the 10k to 300k range.

Comment: Would `select distinct relation_id into ...` will be more efficient ?

Comment: I had presumed the look up selector table (test) contained only distinct relation_id.  Certainly more efficient if test contains duplicates -- likewise, alternate solutions involving uploads of test data, would have a best practice of the uploads being a column slice containing only the distinct relation_ids

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are 3 ways to create an index in `SAS`:

1. Proc Datasets/Modify/Index Create
2. a dataset option (index=), and
3. Proc SQL/ Create Index

AFAIK, the first two are the only way to specify options in addition to `Unique`.

The answer to how to make the join faster will likely involve a combination of (pass-thru) processing in your `Oracle` DB and pre/post processing in `SAS`. And may or may not involve creating indexes.

This will depend on:

- a) where your data is and data size(s), and
- b) what you're trying to achieve in term of result.

Can you provide more info?

EDIT: ok, large table in `Oracle`, small table in `SAS`, small table being the driver of output rows

Without knowing the absolute details, the reason your query was slow had little to do with indexes but rather to do with the fact that you "pulled" through the data from the large Oracle table to satisfy the query.

Easy to fix, as per the last sentence of Richard's updated answer: transfer the small table to Oracle...

To be clear, transfer the small table to Oracle, run the query there and save the results there. Use an appropriate transfer facility to export the data to SAS if required...

Comment: An additional way is the SAS/AF SCL function `ICREATE`

Comment: a) the data is 50 million rows big and is located on a remote server somewhere in a secret place in the middle of Germany :)

Comment: b) It's a very important table, we need to make many joins on 1 to 3 columns of this tables, all of which are well indexed in the oracle database. There are also other tables, usually less big, on which I'd like to leverage those indices.

Comment: So to be clear as the answer to my first question, all these indexing method are equivalent as for their input ? (despite the fact some support more features)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: yes, index methods are the same re input. Re your responses, the remote server is Oracle and the "important table" and "other tables" are on another server in SAS or some other format, right?

Comment: Edit and correction, Data is located on an ORACLE server and on a different SAS server. I have big tables on which I hope to operate joins on each side, but my current issue is relevant to Oracle tables.

Comment: ok. can you clarify: "current issue is relevant to Oracle tables" - I think you mean joining data together from the two environments is the issue, right?

Comment: also: which table is the driver of the required output/rows? for example, are you updating the large table with values from certain rows in the small table? or is it the other way round?

Comment: It's relevant to Oracle tables in the sense that my big table, that I called `MY_TABLE` is in an oracle library. The other table, that I want use in the `join` operation, is either in a SAS library (simply `WORK` in my example), or in another Oracle library (say ORACLELIB2).

Comment: re 'which table is the driver of the required output/rows', I guess typically it will be `smaller_table left join MY_TABLE`, with additional filters on `MY_TABLE`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper: please see "To clarify..."  in my answer

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth, I'm finding more info as we iterate. It happens that the oracle libraries where I can write are on a different server, so your point about the data being copied holds. I think I may have just to copy the full big table in SAS and reindex it.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> If I move my test table to an oracle library these queries are still
>   slow (I cannot index it in this case due to restrictions but it's only
>   one observation).

How did you move to Oracle ? p.s. `ORACLELIB` is not a valid SAS libref, so I'm guessing that is pseudo-code.

Take a look at [SAS/ACCESS® 9.4 for Relational Databases: Reference, Ninth Edition](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=acreldb&docsetTarget=p0he4t6yjfmkhpn16qrf0cdhllu6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en), Example: Create and Join a Permanent Table and a Temporary Table.

The example features `dbmstemp=yes` libname option and

> shows how to use this option to create a permanent and temporary table
>   and then join them in a query.

You could also upload the test table data into a connection session TEMP table, and then selecting the result set via pass-through SQL query.  A pass-through query will let you have full control over the query include host specific features (for example Oracle hints that force index usage) that the SAS remote library engine may not utilize.

Regardless of the join way, the inter-system transfer is likely one of the most time consuming aspects.  You want to find the way that performs the most work on the least transfers.

Comment: Yes it's pseudocode, I renamed the tables and libraries to be sure I don't disclose anything I shouldn't, I create my sample table on the oracle library this way: `data ORACLELIB2.TEST;
   input RELATION_ID;
   datalines;
   1097
;`

Comment: See my hopefully clarified question, now I'll dig into your suggestions and see how I can use them thanks.